# How can I make udisks-glue run at startup and mount drives as particular user?

Tags: mount, raspberry-pi, usb-drive, raspbian, udisks

I'm trying to make [udisks-glue](https://github.com/fernandotcl/udisks-glue) work on my Raspbian Raspberry Pi. This works fine if I manually start `udisks-glue` via ssh. However, I wish to start it automatically on startup.

Hence, a [script](https://gist.github.com/abythell/5399914) at `/etc/init.d/udisks-glue` launches the daemon for me (as per instructions [here](http://angryelectron.com/udisks-glue-initscript/)). This works fine, but disks are mounted with root permissions (`drwx------`). Is it possible to make this script start the daemon as user `pi`, not `root`?

### What I've tried

1) Modifying the script above, replacing

```
DAEMON="/usr/bin/udisks-glue"
```

with

```
DAEMON="exec su - pi -c /usr/bin/udisks-glue"
```

This failed to execute.

2) Replacing this line with a reference to a custom script, which then calls `exec su - pi -c /usr/bin/udisks-glue`. When I connect hard drives, they aren't mounted. However, there is the appearance of correctly running processes. Looking at `ps aux | grep [u]disks`, I can see `udisks-glue` running as `pi` (and two `udisks-daemon`s running as root); I get the same `ps` output if I manually start `udisks-glue`, as above.

3) I tried editing `/etc/rc.local`, adding the line

```
su pi -c "/usr/bin/udisks-glue &"
```

This had the same result as in (2), with `udisks-glue` running as `pi`, but not functional.

4) As per [this page](http://goshawknest.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/how-to-make-usb-disks-readable-by-all-users-on-raspbmc/), running udisks-glue as root, but giving permissions of mounts to all. This works for FAT filesystems, but fails to even mount ext4. (I'd prefer mounts to be owned by user `pi` anyway.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had [the same problem](https://blog.kempniu.pl/en/2012/01/28/non-root-media-mounting-using-udisks-glue.html) a while ago.

#### Solution:

1. *Fixing your configuration:* create file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/50-mount-as-pi.pkla` with the following contents:

   ```
   [Media mounting by pi]
   Identity=unix-user:pi
   Action=org.freedesktop.udisks.filesystem-mount
   ResultAny=yes
   ```
2. *Fixing your init script:*

   - add a variable containing the user you would like to run `udisks-glue` as:

     ```
     NAME=udisks-glue
     PIDFILE=/var/run/udisks.pid
     DAEMON="/usr/bin/udisks-glue"
     DAEMONUSER=pi <-- add this line
     ```
   - modify `start-stop-daemon` invocations to use the `$DAEMONUSER` variable:

     ```
     start) 
         log_daemon_msg "Starting Automounter" "$NAME"
     --> start-stop-daemon --start --exec $DAEMON --chuid $DAEMONUSER
         log_end_msg $?
         ;;
     stop)  
         log_daemon_msg "Stopping Automounter" "$NAME"
     --> start-stop-daemon --stop --exec $DAEMON --user $DAEMONUSER
         log_end_msg $?
         rm -f $PIDFILE
         ;;
     ```

     *(NOTE: I removed the `-- -p $PIDFILE` part from the first invocation. Your regular user account probably won't have write permissions for `/var/run`, so you can either do what I did above or change the `$PIDFILE` variable to a path writable by your regular user.)*

#### Comments on the steps you've taken:

1. This couldn't have worked. The `$DAEMON` variable is used as an argument for `--exec` in a `start-stop-daemon` invocation. That argument should be an **executable**, while `exec` is a [shell builtin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_builtin).
2. Doing that broke your init script. While starting `udisks-glue` that way worked, stopping it wouldn't as `start-stop-daemon` would try to stop `/path/to/your/helper/script.sh` instead of the actual daemon (`/usr/bin/udisks-glue`). Putting that aside, when you start `udisks-glue` in daemon mode, it doesn't generate debug messages. If you ran the following command in an interactive shell:

   ```
   # su pi -c "/usr/bin/udisks-glue -f"
   ```

   you'd probably see something like:

   ```
   Device file /dev/sdb1 inserted
   Trying to automount /dev/sdb1...
   Failed to automount /dev/sdb1: Not Authorized
   Device file /dev/sdb inserted
   ```

   which would've explained why your drives aren't mounted.
3. This was effectively the same as 2. One extra remark: the ampersand (`&`) at the end was redundant as `udisks-glue` daemonizes by default.
4. Again, running `udisks-glue` in foreground would've explained the problem for non-FAT filesystems:

   ```
   Device file /dev/sdb1 inserted
   Trying to automount /dev/sdb1...
   Failed to automount /dev/sdb1: Mount option dmask=0 is not allowed
   Device file /dev/sdb inserted
   ```

   Also note that if you would like to change the owner of an ext4 mountpoint, you need to `chown` it after mounting.

Comment: Wow. This is quite simply the best answer I've received. Clear, addressed all the issues, and even explained my errors. I wish I could + more than 1. Thanks.

Comment: I've reinstalled the system on the Pi, removing a few packages to create a minimal install. These instructions no longer work, and I suspect this is because udisks-glue requires `policykit-1`. However, I'm having trouble [installing it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/144617/how-can-i-install-policykit). I'm not sure if you can help, but I thought it useful to link there anyway.