# How can I install Policykit with System V?

Tags: debian, raspbian, sysvinit, polkit

I created a minimal install on my Raspbian Raspberry Pi running Debian Jessie. Among other things, I removed `libx11-.*` and dependencies, which included removal of `policykit-1`. I'm trying to reinstall `policykit-1`, but hit the following errors.

```
$ sudo apt-get install policykit-1
...
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  sysvinit-core
...
dpkg: sysvinit-core: dependency problems, but removing anyway as you requested:
 sysvinit depends on sysvinit-core | upstart | systemd-sysv; however:
  Package sysvinit-core is to be removed.
  Package upstart is not installed.
  Package systemd-sysv is not installed.
```

After this, booting now hangs, and I have to restore the SD card to an image before this install command. (N.B. booting worked fine before the creation of the minimal install, and after the removal of `libx11-.*` and dependencies.) How can I reinstall `policykit-1`?

---

### Edit

This worked for a little while, but no longer.

There is a long thread [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=747105) discussing how `policykit-1` can break your system in Debian. I didn't read it all, but this (closed) [bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=747397) suggests that `systemd-shim` might be helpful.

Running the following command allowed me to reboot the computer, although I'm unsure as to how functional `policykit-1` is.

```
sudo apt-get install systemd-shim policykit-1
```

However, a recent update to Debian Jessie prevents this from working. `policykit-1` was uninstalled after `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`, and running this command still asks you to uninstall `sysvinit-core`.

Comment: Please provide the output of `apt-rdepends -r policykit-1`

Comment: If that doesn't work try: `apt-cache --installed rdepends policykit-1`

Comment: @eyoung100 Only the seconds works, with `udisks libpolkit-gobject-1-0`

Comment: My hunch here is that the packages need to be reinstalled in the proper order.  Remove `udisks` and `libpolkit-gobject` then reinstall `policykit-1`.  Policykit-1 should reinstall `sysvinit-core and sysvinit`.  You may need to do this in rescue mode, as X may no longer work.

Comment: @eyoung100 As per the question, I don't have X installed. I also don't understand how the order of installation might help here, as (AFAIK) there are no conflicting files installed across the packages. Also, as per the question, `policykit-1` seems to require the removal of `sysvinit-core`, so I'm not sure why we'd expect it to reinstall `sysvinit-core` instead? (It's non-trivial to restore my system when it breaks, so I'd prefer more certain answers.)

Comment: `policykit-1` requires an init system, and the init system requires policykit-1.  `systemd-shim` served as a placeholder for systemd (even though it contained nothing), systemd fulfills the requirement for `init`.  You've hit a classic circular dependancy.  You must uninstall everything that depends on `polkit-1`, then uninstall sysvinit-core, then install polkit-1 then reinstall sysvint, which will pull in *core, and lastly reinstall udisks and libpolkitgobject.  If you need an answer telling you how to do so, I'll write one.

Comment: @eyoung100 I don't believe this is correct.  While systems-shim should provide the prerequisite for policykit-1, it doesn't solve the dependency as the policykit package specifically requires libpam-systemd starting with Jessie.  I've emailed the pkg-utopia-maintainers list, but no one is responding regarding this.

Comment: @pbrunnen: Give it time, or open a bug on launchpad, importance low for pkg- utopia.  A hanging bug always gets someone's attention

Answer (score 0):

For more recent readers:

[Devuan](https://devuan.org/) is a distribution which uses sysvinit by default and includes a [policykit-1](https://pkginfo.devuan.org/stage/ascii/ascii/policykit-1_0.105-18+devuan2.11.html) package that does not depend on systemd. It is mostly compatible with Debian in nearly every respect that does not deal with the init system.